# Get data from Django to Vue Template

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I'm trying to get data from Django to Vuetemplate variables.

views.py

```
def index(request):
  myvar = 1
  return render(request, 'index.html',{'myvar':myvar})
```

in index.html

```
<span> {{ myvar }} </span>
```

Is working, and shows 1, but how can i get this 1/myvar to data inside of the vue instance?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
// here i need the data/value of myvar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the value via params of route

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
// here i need the data/value of myvar
   myvar: this.$route.params.myvar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
    myvar: '{{ myvar }}' //myvar comes from django urls.py
}
```

Works for me, this.$route.params.myvar doesn't cause im not using vuerouter.